# How to apply Patch(.msp) of lower Sequence number ?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, patch, msp

I want to apply a Patch of lower Sequence number on top of already installed Higher sequence number patch. Is this possible without changing any of the patches ? Are there any Windows installer configuration which would ignore Sequence number while installation ?

Answer (score 0):

NO, you can not provide any such configuration for ignoring the sequence number.
The windows installer will not allow the installation to be carried forward for installing patch of lower patch sequence.